# Lambda code migration from node14x to node18x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm working on migrating a lambda function from node v14 to v18. I've written other v18 functions before and the syntax worked just fine. Now when I try the same function after changing the environment of an existing lambda, it is throwing error on a part of code. It feels like half of the code follows the old syntax and half on the new syntax. Can someone tell me what could be the issue here?

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { QueryCommand, DynamoDBDocumentClient } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { DynamoDBClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
const dynamoDBClient = new DynamoDBClient({ signatureVersion: "v4"});
const docClient = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(dynamoDBClient);

var startOfWeek = "";
var endOfWeek = "";
if (moment().isoWeekday() == 6) {
  startOfWeek = moment()
    .subtract(1, "weeks")
    .day("Saturday")
    .startOf("day")
    .toDate()
    .toISOString();
 endOfWeek = moment()
    .subtract(0, "weeks")
    .day("Friday")
    .endOf("day")
    .toDate()
    .toISOString()
} else {
  startOfWeek = moment()
    .subtract(2, "weeks")
    .day("Saturday")
    .startOf("day")
    .toDate()
    .toISOString();
 endOfWeek = moment()
    .subtract(1, "weeks")
    .day("Friday")
    .endOf("day")
    .toDate()
    .toISOString();
}

export const handler = async (event) => {
    let response = {};
    let { agents } = JSON.parse(event.body);
    for(let index in agents){
        let agentLogin = agents[index]
        let sampleData = await getSamples(agentLogin);
        response[agentLogin] = sampleData;
    }
    return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(response),
    };
};

async function getSamples(userLogin){
    //code to get sample and it will return an array
}
```

This is the error I'm facing

```
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
    "trace": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.handler (file:///var/task/index.mjs:39:27)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1147:29)"
    ]
}
```

When I created it from scratch, it accepted this syntax. Now it is the otherway around. What could be the reason and how do I fix it?
Note: Layers added are in node18 version and environment changed to node18. Could confirm it as it is not accepting cjs syntax anymore.

Comment: Node.js != JavaScript

Comment: @jarmod yes that's right, May I know what you're trying to convey here?

Comment: Suspect this is simply that the event.body is undefined causing JSON.parse error (given that your JSON.parse is on line 39 which is the location of the error in the stack trace). It's not a syntax error in your code afaik. Try `JSON.parse(undefined)` in your Node REPL. It will result in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`.

Comment: @helloi Can you explain how you upgraded from v14 to v18? `event.body` shouldn't be non-JSON string, as thats handled by AWS. But I don't see anything in your handler that can cause this error as well.

Comment: @RobinThomas I changed the runtime of the lambda function. as you know v14 uses aws sdk v2 and v18 uses aws sdk v3. There was lot of syntax changes. I had an API gateway that will invoke the lambda function. wondering if it has got anything to do with that

Comment: @jarmod I console logged the event and it was not undefined. and it was not in the event.body. Just in the event and it was not a JSON string. which was not the case when I created it from scratch. Is there any API gateway version changes that had this change?

Comment: No, API Gateway hasn't changed materially, unless you reconfigured your API Gateway api. Are you using [Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) or a custom integration? If you don't know, you should probably be using Lambda proxy integration.